# Recognize two touches tap on two different subviews

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to handle in superview a touch event when there are two touches that land on different subviews.

Can I do it somehow by adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `numberOfTouchesRequired =2;` with a target `self` to a subviews?

Or I need to go something more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject; 
CGPoint referencePoint = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 

if([touch tapCount] == 2){
       //Test touch coordinates to see if theres one in each view
}
```